# Integral of $e^{e^{e^x}}e^{e^{x+x}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrate the function $e^{e^{e^x}}e^{e^{x+x}}$,because I saw this question in a student's homework and I thoght that it would be interesting to try it. I am supposed to use substitution/change of variables in order to do so.

I tried the substitution $e^x = u$ and got the integral of $\frac{1}{u}e^{e^u}e^{u^2}$ and I got stuck, couldn't find any other substitution to simplify it further in order to make it possible to solve this. I tried very hard to do this, but there always appear some weird $log$ there that cannot be carried out.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Hint: as someone pointed out below, I begin to suspect it is wrong in the homework, since it should be simple to solve, since it is an elementary class.

Comment: Is there a motivation for why or is it just curiosity? Often arbitrary integrals do not have closed forms. Also would you mind posting your efforts?

Comment: I will edit the post. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is your $e^{e^{x+x}}$ supposed to be $e^{e^x+x}$?  I believe that will make it much easier and it is not usual to write $x+x$ instead of $2x$

Comment: @RossMillikan I begin to suspect that you are right...

Comment: Hint: in light of your edit, take also $v=e^u$ etc.

Comment: @J.G. I tried this already, but that $\frac{1}{u}$ unfortunately becomes a weird $\frac{1}{log\;v}$. I think I will delete the post, since RossMillikan's comment looks like the truth to me.

Comment: Well, @RossMillikan's guess as to which problem is intended implies such a substitution will work. Better than deleting the question would be to [answer it yourself](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @J.G. suggestion accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the problem is probably written wrong. It probably should be $e^{e^{e^x}}e^{e^x+x} = e^{e^{e^x}}e^{e^x}e^x$. Then one could use the substitution $e^{e^x} = u$ and get to the integral of $e^{u}$. Then the answer would be easily be found to be $e^{e^{e^x}}+k$.